# Checkers move validator in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, chess

I have 3 classes to create a simple checkers move validator. The entry point is checkers.py and is mostly complete with a few things hard-coded. For example, the auto-generated board (if none is given) starts with the upper left square as white, whereas if we are given a board, we are assuming the upper left square is black (black = legal square we can move to, white squares we cannot move to). Also when validating a move, we are only considering the case where the piece we are moving can move diagonally downwards (e.g. the piece started at the top of the board and is not a king).

I feel like my design is not very good and there is too much hard-coding, so I want to get some feedback before I continue any further. Please let me know what improvements I can make.

#### checkers.py

```
from piece import Piece, Side
from validator import Validator


class Checkers:
    '''
    Checkers class can either generate an empty board or take in a board. The two different checkers boards available
    are either top left square black or white and then they alternate. I have top left color as black hard coded ri
    ght now (if a board is given). If a board is not given, the board is harded coded for top left color as white.
    '''
    def __init__(self, board=None):
        self.BOARD_ROWS, self.BOARD_COLS = 8, 8
        self.legal_spaces = set()
        if not board:
            self.board = [[None for _ in range(self.BOARD_COLS)] for _ in range(self.BOARD_ROWS)]
            for row in range(self.BOARD_ROWS):
                if (row % 2) == 0:
                    for col in range(1, self.BOARD_COLS, 2):
                        self.legal_spaces.add((row, col))
                        if 0 <= row <= 2:
                            self.board[row][col] = Piece(Side.RED)
                        elif 5 <= row <= 7:
                            self.board[row][col] = Piece(Side.BLACK)
                else:
                    for col in range(0, self.BOARD_COLS, 2):
                        self.legal_spaces.add((row, col))
                        if 0 <= row <= 2:
                            self.board[row][col] = Piece(Side.RED)
                        elif 5 <= row <= 7:
                            self.board[row][col] = Piece(Side.BLACK)
        elif Validator.validate_board(board):
            self.board = board
            self.generate_legal_spaces('B')
            for row in range(self.BOARD_ROWS):
                for col in range(self.BOARD_COLS):
                    match board[row][col]:
                        case 'R':
                            board[row][col] = Piece(Side.RED)
                        case 'B':
                            board[row][col] = Piece(Side.BLACK)
                        case _:
                            board[row][col] = None
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Board.')

    def generate_legal_spaces(self, top_left_color):
        if top_left_color not in ('B', 'W'):
            raise ValueError('Incorrect top left color provided')
        for row in range(self.BOARD_ROWS):
                if top_left_color == 'B':
                    if (row % 2 == 0):
                        self.legal_spaces.update([(row, 0), (row, 2), (row, 4), (row, 6)])
                    else:
                        self.legal_spaces.update([(row, 1), (row, 3), (row, 5), (row, 7)])
                else:
                    if (row % 2 == 0):
                        self.legal_spaces.update([(row, 1), (row, 3), (row, 5), (row, 7)])
                    else:
                        self.legal_spaces.update([(row, 0), (row, 2), (row, 4), (row, 6)])

    def __str__(self):
        output = ''
        for row in range(self.BOARD_ROWS):
            for col in range(self.BOARD_COLS):
                square = self.board[row][col]
                if not square:
                    output += '_'
                else:
                    output += square.side.value
                if col != self.BOARD_COLS - 1:
                    output += ' '
            if row != self.BOARD_ROWS - 1:
                output+= '\n'
        return output
```

#### validator.py

```
from piece import Side


class Validator:
    @staticmethod
    def validate_board(board):
        BOARD_ROWS, BOARD_COLS = 8, 8
        invalid_vectors = [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)]
        if len(board) != BOARD_ROWS:
            return False

        def occupied(location):
            row, col = location[0], location[1]
            if (0 <= row <= 7) and (0 <= col <= 7) and board[row][col]:
                return True
            return False

        for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
            for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
                curr_location = (row, col)
                if occupied(curr_location):
                    for invalid_vector in invalid_vectors:
                        invalid_candidate = tuple([sum(x) for x in zip(curr_location, invalid_vector)])
                        if occupied(invalid_candidate):
                            return False
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def valid_location(legal_spaces, location):
        row, col = location[0], location[1]
        if not (0 <= row <= 7) or not (0 <= col <= 7):
            return False
        if location not in legal_spaces:
            return False
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def occupied(board, location):
        return not Validator.unoccupied(board, location)

    @staticmethod
    def unoccupied(board, location):
        row, col = location[0], location[1]
        if not (0 <= row <= 7) or not (0 <= col <= 7):
            return False
        return not board[row][col]

    @staticmethod
    def occupied_side(board, location, side):
        # is square within board and occupied by the color given in side
        row, col = location[0], location[1]
        if not (0 <= row <= 7) or not (0 <= col <= 7):
            return False
        piece = board[row][col]
        if piece and piece.side == side:
            return True
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def validate_move(board, legal_spaces, start, end):
        '''
        Only handles the case where starting piece is red and not a king,
        so we can only move diagonally downwards
        '''
        if not Validator.valid_location(legal_spaces, start) or not \
            Validator.valid_location(legal_spaces, end):
            raise ValueError('Provided start or end location is out of bounds')
        start_row, start_col = start[0], start[1]
        end_row, end_col = end[0], end[1]
        # check if we are ending at unoccupied square
        if Validator.occupied(board, end):
            return False
        piece = board[start_row][start_col]
        villain_side = Side.BLACK if (piece.side == Side.RED) else Side.RED
        move_vectors = [(1, -1), (1, 1)]
        jump_vectors = [{'villain_vector': (1, -1), 'captured_vector': (2, -2)}, \
            {'villain_vector': (1, 1), 'captured_vector': (2, 2)}]
        # can we get to end by just moving
        for move_vector in move_vectors:
            move_candidate = tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(start, move_vector))
            if Validator.unoccupied(board, move_candidate) and move_candidate == end:
                return True
        # cannot get to end by move, need to jump
        return Validator.validate_jump(board, legal_spaces, jump_vectors, start, end, villain_side)

    @staticmethod
    def validate_jump(board, legal_spaces, jump_vectors, curr, target, villain_side):
        if curr == target:
            return True
        if curr in legal_spaces:
            for jump_vector in jump_vectors:
                villain_candidate = tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(curr, jump_vector['villain_vector']))
                jump_candidate = tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(curr, jump_vector['captured_vector']))
                if Validator.occupied_side(board, villain_candidate, villain_side) and Validator.unoccupied(board, jump_candidate):
                    villain_row, villain_col = villain_candidate[0], villain_candidate[1]
                    captured_piece = board[villain_row][villain_col]
                    board[villain_row][villain_col] = None
                    return Validator.validate_jump(board, legal_spaces, jump_vectors, jump_candidate, target, villain_side)
                    board[villain_row][villain_col] = captured_piece
        return False
```

#### piece.py

```
from enum import Enum

class Side(Enum):
    RED = 'R'
    BLACK = 'B'

class Piece:
    def __init__(self, side):
        if side not in (Side.RED, Side.BLACK):
            raise ValueError('Piece must be either red or black and be of type Side.')
        self.side = side
        self.is_king = False

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Color: {self.side}, King: {self.is_king}>'
```